# Getting error while exporting ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode8

I am getting below error for my Hybrid Cordova 6.5 App powered with IBM MobileFirst 8 when I am trying to export the app:

```
2017-02-24 21:54:40 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
2017-02-24 21:54:40 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}


2017-02-24 22:05:30 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: App Name, task: Validate
2017-02-24 22:05:30 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreValidation: 0x7f8ca08aefb0>
2017-02-24 22:05:31 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f8c9f9ad2b0:'/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-02-24 22:05:31 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f8ca0a58e60:'/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationPush.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationPush.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/ptiwari/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-02-24/App Name 2-24-17, 4.05 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/App Name.app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationPush.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-02-24 22:05:35 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Comment: I get this same error when I export the project. I started getting it after adding cordova-plugin-mfp-push@~8.0.2017012410 plugin. If I remove this plugin I don't have the error.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided below?

Comment: Which one? I don't want to completly remove the platform since I have some custom native modifications

Comment: I just explained my errors and all the logs at another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250159/cordova-plugin-mfp-push-causing-unexpected-mach-o-header-error

Comment: In my case...Removing and adding back the platform resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the cordova plugins and added them back again. Then I removed the ios platform and add it again. Then I opened the xcode and tried exporting my app again, it got exported successfully.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this relates to the following: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/prepare-ios-apps-for-app-store-submission/

1. Select Build Phases tab in Xcode project settings
2. Add new Run Script Phase
3. Paste the following script inside Run Script tab

   ```
   APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

   find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
   do
       FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
       FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
       echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

       EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

       for ARCH in $ARCHS
       do
            echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
            lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
            EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
       done

       echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
       lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
       rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

       echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
       rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
       mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

   done
   ```

Comment: Same here, issue is not resolved after adding the shell script. Issue appeared after adding the mfp-push plugin

Comment: When I remove cordova-plugin-mfp-push, I can export the build, when I add the cordova-plugin-mfp-push plugin (cordova-plugin-mfp-push@~8.0.2017012410), I can't export the build and I have the mentioned errors

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any third part SDK. Set this.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4450

Comment: The Only Thirt Party SDK I am using are IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework and IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationPush.framework